# React component is not re-rendering on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am dispatching an object to an array and I get an information that it was sended successfully but length of this array hasn't changed in my Header component. There

```
store.getState().Basket.length
```

is not re-rendering. The value only re-renders when I change the path.

This is Header component:

```
function Header() {
  return (
    <div id="Header">
      <Link to='/' style={{ display: 'flex',textDecoration: 'none', color: '#000' }}>
        <div className='Header_Pole'>
          <img src={logo} alt='Logo' className='Header_Pole_img'/>   
        </div>
      </Link>
      <Link to='/basket' style={{ display: 'flex',textDecoration: 'none', color: '#000' }}>
        <div className='Header_Pole'>
          <img src={shoppingBasketIcon} alt='Basket' className='Header_Pole_img'/> 
          <p className='itemsCounter'>{ store.getState().Basket.length }</p>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

store:

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        Basket: basketReducer
    }
  })
```

dispatch function:

```
const addToBasket = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: addtoBASKET,
      item: {
      id: Products[idOfProduct - 1].id,
      name:Products[idOfProduct - 1].name,
      type: Products[idOfProduct - 1].type,
      image: Products[idOfProduct - 1].image,
      price:Products[idOfProduct - 1].price,
      size: gettingSize() // return a size
      }
    })
  }
```

I tried to find some stuff on the internet but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the hook `useSelector` from `react-redux`
`useSelector` will notify your component when the redux state change and update your component

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

function Header() {
  const basketLength = useSelector((state)=>state.Basket.length)
  return (
    <div id="Header">
       // [...]
       <p className='itemsCounter'>{basketLength}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`react-redux`](https://react-redux.js.org) to work with redux state in react. Otherwise you'd have to implement state synchronization between the two manually.

Comment: The OP has included `react-redux` as a tag for this question. This would suggest they're using it.

Comment: But he is not using it the way `react-redux` expected to be used. Specifically he isn't using neither `useSelector()` nor `useDispatch()` hooks in the code, which are  `react-redux`-specific hooks and without them there is no point using it.

Comment: this answer is lacking the derail I think it should have, but the overall point is unquestionably right - by using the React Redux API everything will be taken care of, while what the OP is trying to do in explicitly accessing the store in the component, does not lead to rerenders because the component isn't actually connected to the Redux store via props or state.

Comment: @BillerBuilder - that's the information you need to include in your answer, probably with a [mcve] on _how_ it should be used.

Comment: That's literally in react-redux docs though in the "get started" section.

Comment: @BillerBuilder The point here is that your answer should be *something more than* "you should use [link to docs] ... go figure it out". It's a *somewhat* helpful comment, pointing them in a direction, but not a very useful answer.